# How to display user's profile photo in custom Oracle WebCenter template?

Tags: jakarta-ee, webcenter

I'm working on a custom template for Oracle WebCenter, created from the scratch in JDeveloper. I woudl like to display a logged-in user avatar (or profile photo) in the upper right of the template. Just like it's done on thousands of pages. How to do it?

While googling and experimenting, I've found that there's ProfilePhotoServlet in the webcenter, that displays user photo in WebCenter Spaces. It should work (the servlet is running in my WebCenter app), but I need to specify somehow the user to make it work.

In webcenter spaces it goes like:

```
<img src="/webcenter/profilephoto/3039374139443130393142413131453042464632374433413541413746423930/SMALL/1319467188271?_xResourceMethod=wsrp" />
```

And the user's picture appears. I have no idea how to obtain those numeric params for the ProfilePhotoServlet.

Answer (score 2):

```
<af:image source="#{
        webCenterProfile[(pageFlowScope.userId == null ? securityContext.userName : pageFlowScope.userId)]
        .photoURI[not empty pageFlowScope.imageSize? pageFlowScope.imageSize : 'MEDIUM']
        }" shortDesc="#{pageFlowScope.userId}" id="i22">
</af:image>
```